# Read a POM file property value into a "<file_name>.properties" file

Tags: java, maven, selenium

1) I have a property file that has the content as follows:

selenium.browser=${selenium.browser}

2) I have a POM file that has the Properties tag as below:

```
<properties>
    <selenium.browser>chrome</selenium.browser>
    <selenium.environment>dev</selenium.environment>
</properties>
```

3) In the same POM file, I also have resources tag to bind the ".properties" file with POM:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

After the third step, if I do ctrl + mouse hover then I can see the value 'chrome' from POM into the .properties file. (Editor: Intellij Idea)

4) And finally I have a java class to read the value of ${selenium.browser} (i.e. chrome) with the code as below:

```
public static String getProperties(String propName) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
    } catch (Exception e){}
    return prop.getProperty(propName);

}
```

Question: If I call getProperties method then I get the output as "${selenium.browser}" instead of "chrome".

Comment: what is the value of propName?

Comment: selenium.browser

Comment: what is the location of resource file? is it under src/main or src/main/resource ?

Comment: It is under 'src/main/resources'. Actually i have put one more file with the same name and content under 'src/main'. Still it isn't working.. thank you for your questions..

Comment: did you try updating POM with the directory - src/main/resources

Comment: Apologies for the delay.. Yes I did, but it still didn't work..